# Grab values from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I am building a dictionary.  I would like to log out a list of one field in the dictionary, the ids, but not succeeding.

Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
    item =  fetchedObjects[i];
    tmpDict[item.tid] = item;
}
NSLog(@"list of items%@",tmpDict);
```

This lists all the items but what I really want is a list of just the ids.

Something like `NSLog(@"list of item ids:%@",tmpDict.tid);` but this throws error.

Comment: where r u storing the info into dictionary ?  can you show the dictionary format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases where the key value coding method `valueForKey:` is useful. It returns an array of all values for the specific key of all dictionaries in the array.

```
NSLog(@"list of items%@", [fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"tid"]);
```

The repeat loop can be omitted.

In the cases to retrieve **one** value for a key, use `objectForKey:` Both methods are often mistaken for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array of ids, there is no need for the `tmpDict`.

You can do this manually like this:

```
NSMutableArray *ids = [NSMutableArray array];
for (WhatEverClass *item in fetchedObjects) {
    [ids addObject:item.tid];
}
NSLog(@"ids = %@", ids);
```

Or do it the easy way with KVC:

```
NSArray *ids = [fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"tid"];
NSLog(@"ids = %@", ids);
```